# Variable Substiution in sed executing via python

Tags: python, sed, variable-substitution

Below is my sed command:

> sed "s/N([0-9]*)/sum('\1')/g" old.txt > new.txt

works fine in bash terminal

But below python code doesnot execute :-

```
file1=old.txt
file2.new.txt
sed_cmd = 'sed "s/0x\([0-9]*\)/sum('\1')/g" %s > %s' %(file1,file2)
```

I get syntax error

After above I need do :-

```
subprocess.call([sed_cmd],shell=True)
```

Comment: Escape your single quotes like `sum(\'\1\')...`

Comment: but \1 not getting value now

Comment: it comes like this sed "s/0x\([0-9]*\)/sum('')/g" old.txt > new.txt

Comment: escape the `\` as well `\\1`

Comment: use raw strings for the sed command and then concatenate the files separately.. something like `r'''sed "s/0x\([0-9]*\)/sum('\1')/g" ''' + '%s > %s' %(file1,file2)`

Comment: thank @Sundeep works

Comment: thanks @C.Nivs for ur help

Answer (score 0):

Main issues:

- Single quotes `'` are used unescaped in a regular single quoted string literal (that make the syntax corrupt)
- `\1` inside a regular string literal defines a `\x01` character, a SOH char, and not a regex backreference (that requires two char combination, `\` + here, `1`).

You can use

```py
sed_cmd = r"""sed "s/0x\([0-9]*\)/sum('\1')/g" {} > {}""".format(file1,file2)
```

**Details**:

- `r"""..."""` is a *triple-quoted* raw string literal inside which you may freely use unescaped `'` and `"`, and `\` chars denote literal backslashes
- `{}` are placeholders in the format string, the first one will be filled with the contents of the first and second variables passed as arguments in parentheses (see `.format(file1,file2)`).